# It was the first time we had been to Brasil or It was the first time we had been in Brasil

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, word-choice

It was the first time we had been to Brasil or
It was the first time we had been in Brasil.

Comment: The English name is Bra**z**il.

Comment: Hello, Hennadiyevna, welcome to ELU! Please take some time for the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). The custom here is to show what you have found using a dictionary or grammar. This helps us to better understand the question and where your doubt is. Cheers!

Comment: Michael Harvey thanks! Any help in grammar?

Comment: See above comment.

Comment: You are so kind and polite